# Expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have following class definition. While trying to build it, I'm coming across strange error. I don't see any mistake here. Any ideas?

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include "room.h"
#include "person_session.h"

class Server{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    Room room;
    void accept();
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint):acceptor(ioc,endpoint){
        accept();
    }
};

#endif
```

> ```
> expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
>      Server(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint):acceptor(ioc,endpoint){}
>                                    ^ 
> CMakeFiles/server.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/server.dir/src/server.cpp.o' failed
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/server.dir/src/server.cpp.o] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/server.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/server.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

Comment: acceptor(ioc,endpoint) -> acceptor(std::move(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor((ioc,endpoint))

Comment: Getting rid of it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Try this: `acceptor(ioc,endpoint)` change to `acceptor(std::move(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(ioc,endpoint)))`

Comment: The error message says "io_concept" where the code says "io_context." Are you sure this is the code the error refers to?

Comment: @artona It doesn't work :/

Comment: @Wintermute My typo, edited already

Comment: That indicates there can be other "tyops", use copy paste of the real thing.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I updated full message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`io_context` is a new name that was added in Boost 1.66 for compatibility with the C++ Networking TS. You must be using an older Boost version.

[This page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html) suggests that the old name was `io_service`, and this name will also be supported in new versions.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I changed it and it worked! :)